# Reference Javascript object from string

Tags: javascript

Given data similar to:

```
var data = [{id: 12345, 
    name:'my products', 
    items:[{ 
               size: 'XXL', 
               sku: 'awe2345', 
               prices:[{type: 'rrp',prices: 10.99}, 
                        {type: 'sell_price', price: 9.99}, 
                         {type:'dealer', price:4.50} 
               ] 
               },{ 
               size: 'XL', 
               sku: 'awe2346', 
               prices:[{type: 'rep', prices: 10.99}, 
                          {type: 'sell_price', price: 9.99}, 
                          {type:'dealer', price:4.50} 
               ] 
               } 
       ] 
   }] 
}]
```

is there a way to evaluate a string representation of an element in the data object? for example: "data[0].items[0].prices[0].rrp" ...without using eval()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to not have the string representation in the first place. ***Seriously*** ask yourself whether you change the existing code to give you the content in a more ideal output.

However, if you can't, this should do what you want:

```
var path = "data[0].items[0].prices[0].rrp".split(/[\[\]\.]+/);
var next = window;

if (path[path.length - 1] == "") {
    path.pop();
};

while (path.length && (next = next[path.shift()]) && typeof next == "object" && next !== null);

next;
```

Create a function for this:

```
function get(path) {
    var next = window;

    path = path.split(/[\[\]\.]+/);

    if (path[path.length - 1] == "") {
        path.pop();
    };

    while (path.length && (next = next[path.shift()]) && typeof next === "object" && next !== null);

    return path.length ? undefined : next;
}
```

**Downsides:**

1. The variable `data` must be in the global scope for this to work (cannot be a local variable).
2. It's skanky. Use it as a last resort.

**Edit:** To use setting functionality, you can abuse the pass-by-reference nature of JavaScript objects as follows:

```
function set(path, value) {
    var split = Math.max(path.lastIndexOf("["), path.lastIndexOf("."));

    get(path.slice(0, split))[path.slice(split + 1).replace(/\]/, "")] = value;
}
```

**To provide some explanation of how this works:**

The *getter* first splits the input into an array, so that each element is a member we need to traverse `[data, 0, items, 0, prices, 0, rrp]`. If the search string ends with a "]", we get an extra empty-element at the end of the array, so we check for that and remove it.

We then do the big loop; so whist we have elements to traverse (`while path.length`), set the `next` variable to the next object member we need to traverse `next = next[path.shift()]`. Check that it's an object (otherwise it wont have any members to traverse), and check that it isn't null (because typeof null == "object").

Once the loop has executed, we'll have the final element in the chain; so return it.

The *setter* searches for the last object reference in the search string, and retrieves that object reference using the `get()` function. It then sets the returned objects key to the desired value. If we hadn't done it this way, we'd have been setting a value rather than a reference, so the "real" object would never get updated.

Comment: Agreed - a brilliant suggestion which works. ...although I'm still struggling to get my head around exactly how it works! However, ideally I needed a reference to the specified element of the object to allow for setting as well as getting - can you suggest how that could be done?

Comment: @Alistair: I've added code for setting values, and tried to provide some explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 4):

Matt's solution is pure genius - however there is some room for improvement:

- The solution fails if the 'path' has no separators; `set('h1', somevalue)` will fail because the splitting of the path fails in that case
- Only global scope is supported.
- If you have an object with `obj.here.is.a.value = "I am a value"` and you ask for `obj.here.is.a.value.no.value` - it will still return "I am a value"

Here's my fix for these three issues:

```
    getPropertyValueByPath : function(obj, path)
    {
        path = path.split(/[\[\]\.]+/);

        if(path[path.length - 1] == "")
        {
            path.pop();
        };

        while(path.length && ( obj = obj[path.shift()]));

        return obj;
    }


setPropertyValuebyPath : function(obj, path, value)
    {
        var pathElements = path.replace(/\[|\]/g, '.').replace(/\.+/g, '.').split(/\./)
        pathEnd = pathElements[pathElements.length - 1]
        pathRoot = (pathElements.slice(0, pathElements.length - 1).join('.'))

        var currObj = obj

        for(var i = 0; i < pathElements.length; i++)
        {

            if( typeof (currObj[pathElements[i]]) == 'undefined')
            {
                currObj[pathElements[i]] = {}
            }
            currObj = currObj[pathElements[i]]
        }
        // This line by Matt is genious :)
        getPropertyValueByPath(obj, pathRoot)[pathEnd] = value
        return true
    }
```

call them like this:

```
var joe = {}

setPropertyValueByPath(joe,'the[1].long.and[2].road', 'yeah')

// joe.the[1].long.and[2].road now has a value of 'yeah' - 
// all the missing objects were created

// this will alert 'yeah'
alert( getPropertyValueByPath(joe,'the[1].long.and[2].road') )
```

Comment: and end node array handling jsfiddle.net/UQTBK/5 so you can have (joe, 'the[1].long.and[2].road[3]', 'yeah')

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand that question, but I guess you want to "select" that object within the inner Array ?

If thats the case, you need to loop over that inner Array.

```
Object.keys( data[0].items[0].prices[0] ).some(function( obj ) {
    if( obj.type === 'rrp' ) {
        // do something with that object here
        return true;
    }
});
```

To have that code ES3 compliant, we would go for:

```
var target = data[0].items[0].prices[0],
    len    = target.length;

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if( target[i].type === 'rrp' ) {
        // do something with target[i]
        break;
    } 
}
```

If I got the question wrong, doh sorry for your time :-)

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a generic way of achieving this. e.g. given a string "data[0].items[0].prices[0].rrp" and returning 10.99 or a string of "data[0].items[1]" and returning the object.

Comment: @AlistairFleming: got it. However, even with `eval` it would not work to call/execute that string you mentioned. You need a loop and compare values.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a getter instead of an exposed public field, you can make your way there doing some post-processing before the first return of your collection:

```
   var data = [{
        id: 12345,
        name: 'my products',
        items: [{
            size: 'XXL',
            sku: 'awe2345',
            prices: [{ type: 'rrp', price: 10.99 },
                    { type: 'sell_price', price: 9.99 },
                    { type: 'dealer', price: 4.50 }
                   ]
        }, {
            size: 'XL',
            sku: 'awe2346',
            prices: [{ type: 'rep', price: 10.99 },
                            { type: 'sell_price', price: 9.99 },
                            { type: 'dealer', price: 4.50}]
        }
            ],
        getItems: function () {
            if (!this._applied) {
                this._applied = true;
                for (var i = 0; i <  this.items.length; i++) {
                    this.items[i].prices = this._asCrossReferencable(this.items[i].prices);
                }
            }
            return this.items;
        },
        _asCrossReferencable: function (priceArr) {
            for (var i = 0; i < priceArr.length; i++) {
                priceArr[i][priceArr[i].type] = priceArr[i].price;
            }
            return priceArr;
        },
        _applied: false
    }];

    var items = data[0].getItems();
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        for(var p = 0; p < items[i].prices.length; p++){
            var price = items[i].prices[p];
            alert(price[price.type]);
        }
    }
```

That's a lot of bloat though just for some lazy shorthand.